# CONSULTA SQL usando função MAX

Tags: sql, query

Estou com um problema numa consulta básica de *SQL*, é para uma migração de *banco de dados*.

A consulta tem como finalidade trazer os dados da tabela de `ASSOCIADOS/CLIENTES`, mas além dessa tabela eu tenho outra de `MENSALIDADES`, e dois dos campos que eu preciso nessa extração é o vencimento da ultima mensalidade e o seu valor.

Estou usando o `MAX` para trazer a mensalidade e até aí tudo certo, quando coloco:

```
 CONVERT (VARCHAR,MAX(MEN.VENCIMENTO),102) as data_inicio_ciclo
```

o valor retornado é realmente da última mensalidade e não duplica a informação, o valor na consulta ela traz todos os dados, sendo que preciso somente do valor do último:

```
 MEN.Valor AS valor_total_venda
```

Abaixo a consulta no SQL e o retorno (PRINT) com o VALOR e SEM O VALOR

```
SELECT
        ASS.Inscricao as numero_contrato,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR, ASS.data, 102) as data_contrato,
        ASS.grupo as id_tipo_contrato,
        ASS.TipoVenda as id_tipo_venda,
        ASS.Inscricao as codigo_cliente_antigo,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.data, 102) as data_vigencia_inicial,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DataContratoVigenciaFinal, 102) as data_vigencia_final,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DiaVenc, 102) as dia_vencimento,
        ASS.AssTipoCobranca as id_preferencia_faturamento,
        ASS.AssTipoCobranca as id_periodicidade,
        ASS.AssTipoCobranca as ciclo_atual,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR,MAX(MEN.VENCIMENTO),102) as data_inicio_ciclo,
        ASS.status as registro_ativo,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DataStatus, 102) as data_cancelamento,
        ASS.MotivoStat as id_motivo_cancelamento,
        ASS.Obs1 as observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
        ASS.Obs2 as observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
        MEN.Valor as valor_total_venda


from Associados as ASS
    inner join mensalidade as MEN ON MEN.INSCRICAO=ASS.INSCRICAO 
where ASS.Inscricao ='1'

GROUP BY    
            ASS.Inscricao, 
            ASS.Data, 
            ASS.Grupo, 
            ASS.TipoVenda, 
            ASS.DataContratoVigenciaFinal,
            ASS.DiaVenc,
            ASS.AssTipoCobranca,
            ASS.Status,
            ASS.DataStatus,
            ASS.MotivoStat,
            ASS.Obs1,
            ASS.Obs2,
            men.valor
```

[image: CONSULTA SEM INCLUIR O VALOR]

Comment: parece (pela descrição, deveria colocar mais dados para facilitar a análise) que algum dos campos agrupados está com valores iguais por isso está duplicando, tente ordenar para tirar a dúvida

Comment: A coluna `MEN.Valor` retorna o total de todos os registros agrupados?

Comment: Ela não está trazendo registros iguais, traz vários vencimentos e em alguns casos aparece o men.valor agrupado.

Answer (score -1):

Trecho inicial da consulta (comum aos dois excertos abaixo):

```
SELECT
    ASS.Inscricao as numero_contrato,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR, ASS.data, 102) as data_contrato,
    ASS.grupo as id_tipo_contrato,
    ASS.TipoVenda as id_tipo_venda,
    ASS.Inscricao as codigo_cliente_antigo,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.data, 102) as data_vigencia_inicial,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DataContratoVigenciaFinal, 102) as data_vigencia_final,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DiaVenc, 102) as dia_vencimento,
    ASS.AssTipoCobranca as id_preferencia_faturamento,
    ASS.AssTipoCobranca as id_periodicidade,
    ASS.AssTipoCobranca as ciclo_atual,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,MEN.MaxVENCIMENTO,102) as data_inicio_ciclo,
    ASS.status as registro_ativo,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DataStatus, 102) as data_cancelamento,
    ASS.MotivoStat as id_motivo_cancelamento,
    ASS.Obs1 as observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
    ASS.Obs2 as observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
    MEN.Valor as valor_total_venda
from Associados as ASS
....
```

Dividi em dois excertos, abaixo, o primeiro NÃO classificando por `Inscricao` e o segundo, sim.

```
....
-- O trecho abaixo traz o maior valor geral para o 
-- campo Vencimento e o Valor, sem classificar por campo Inscricao
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 Vencimento AS MaxVencimento,
           Valor,
           Inscricao
    FROM Mensalidade
    ORDER BY Vencimento DESC
) as MEN 
where ASS.Inscricao ='1'
```

Veja agora o seguinte trecho para classificar por `Inscricao`:

```
....
-- O trecho abaixo traz o maior valor para o 
-- campo Vencimento e o Valor, classificados por campo Inscricao
JOIN (
    SELECT m1.MaxVencimento, m1.Inscricao, m2.Valor
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(Vencimento) AS MaxVencimento,
               Inscricao
        FROM Mensalidade
        GROUP BY Inscricao
        ) as m1
    JOIN 
        Mensalidade m2 
        ON m2.Inscricao = m1.Inscricao AND m2.Vencimento = m1.MaxVencimento
) as MEN ON MEN.Inscricao = Ass.Inscricao 
where ASS.Inscricao ='1'
```

Comment: Confesso que não entendi... tenho pouco conhecimento de SQL, faço apenas consultas básicas (por mais que saiba que isso é básico), então não entendi como aplicar este conceito explicado e em qual momento utilizar. Fiz alguns testes aqui e não deu certo.

Comment: Os dois trechos acima são mutuamente excludentes, ou seja, se usar um, *não* use o outro. O trecho inicial já é comum aos dois.

Comment: Que erro aparece?

Comment: Estou classificando o máximo valor de data de vencimento por `Inscricao` na subquery de baixo e, na de cima, eu pego o máximo valor *geral* de data de vencimento.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

Você pode usar uma subquery para pegar a maio data de vencimento para cada assinante, dai montar o inner join usando esta subquery, da uma olhada

```
        SELECT
                ASS.Inscricao                                               AS numero_contrato,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR, ASS.data, 102)                             AS data_contrato,
                ASS.grupo                                                   AS id_tipo_contrato,
                ASS.TipoVenda                                               AS id_tipo_venda,
                ASS.Inscricao                                               AS codigo_cliente_antigo,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR,ASS.data, 102)                              AS data_vigencia_inicial,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR,ASS.DataContratoVigenciaFinal, 102)         AS data_vigencia_final,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR,ASS.DiaVenc, 102)                           AS dia_vencimento,
                ASS.AssTipoCobranca                                         AS id_preferencia_faturamento,
                ASS.AssTipoCobranca                                         AS id_periodicidade,
                ASS.AssTipoCobranca                                         AS ciclo_atual,
                CONVERT (VARCHAR,MEN.VENCIMENTO,102)                        AS data_inicio_ciclo,
                ASS.status                                                  AS registro_ativo,
                CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASS.DataStatus, 102)                       AS data_cancelamento,
                ASS.MotivoStat                                              AS id_motivo_cancelamento,
                ASS.Obs1                                                    AS observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
                ASS.Obs2                                                    AS observacoes1, -- REVALIDAR
                MEN.Valor                                                   AS valor_total_venda


        from Associados as ASS
        inner join mensalidade as MEN ON MEN.INSCRICAO = ASS.INSCRICAO 
                                      and MEN.VENCIMENTO = (
                                                            SELECT MAX(C.VENCIMENTO)
                                                            FROM mensalidade AS C
                                                            WHERE  C.INSCRICAO = ASS.INSCRICAO 
                                                            )
        where ASS.Inscricao ='1'
```

Com isto voce não precisa nem dar **GROUP BY**

Answer (score -3):

Amigo bom dia, pq ao invé desssa consulta gigantesca vc usa as variaveis de max, exemplo.

Ao invés disso:

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR,MAX(MEN.VENCIMENTO),102) as data_inicio_ciclo
```

usa isso :

```
Declare @Vencimento datetime =(Select MAX(MEN.VENCIMENTO) Vencimento 
                               From  Associados
                               where Inscricao = 1)  
CONVERT (VARCHAR,@Vencimento,102) as data_inicio_ciclo
```

Não entendi o real motivo do seu filtro estar entre aspas, sendo que deve ser booleano ou integer, mas espero que te ajude.